# Any difference between clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME .... ) and time()?

Tags: c++, c, datetime, time

A simple question: do `time(...)` and `clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, ... )` produce the same time theoretically (in respect to seconds only)?

---

Here's what I mean:

```
time_t epoch;
time( &epoch );
```

and

```
struct timespec spec;
clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec );
```

Are these two supposed to return exactly the same result (in respect to seconds)?

I "tested" this with changing time and time zones and `epoch` and `spec.tv_sec` always show the same result, but the documentation of `CLOCK_REATIME` confuses me a bit and I'm not sure, that they will always be the same.

---

Real world situation: I have a piece of code, which uses `time`. Now I want to have the time in milliseconds (which can be taken from `spec.tv_nsec`, multiplied by 1000000). So I think about removing `time` and using directly `clock_gettime`, but I'm not sure if this will remain the same in all situations.

---

<sub>The question is somehow related to [Measure time in Linux - time vs clock vs getrusage vs clock_gettime vs gettimeofday vs timespec_get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392278/measure-time-in-linux-time-vs-clock-vs-getrusage-vs-clock-gettime-vs-gettimeof) but the information there was not enough for me.. I think.</sub>

Comment: In C++ there is also third option, `std::chrono::system_clock::now()`.

Comment: @dreamlax Yep, but the new standard cannot be used for my case, that's why I explicitly asked for these two. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Note: I used the git master branch and v4.7 for the reference links below, x86 only, as I'm lazy.]

`time()` is in fact an alias for the equally named syscall, which calls `get_seconds`, happens at [`kernel/time/time.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/time.c). That syscall uses the [`get_seconds`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L2140) function to return the UNIX timestamp, which is read from the core timekeeping struct, more precisely from the "Current CLOCK_REALTIME time in seconds" field (`xtime_sec`).

`clock_gettime()` is a glibc function in `sysdeps\unix\clock_gettime.c`, which simply calls `gettimeofday` if the supplied clock ID is `CLOCK_REALTIME`, which is again backed by the equally named syscall (source is in the same `time.c` file, above). This one calls [`do_gettimeofday`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L1141), which eventually ends up calling [`__getnstimeofday64`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L643), that queries... the very same `xtime_sec` field from the same struct as above.

Update:

As @MaximEgorushkin cleverly pointed out, a new vDSO mechanism hijacks (a good sign it is present, if your binary depends on `linux-vdso.so.*`) the `clock_gettime` call and redirects it to `__vdso_clock_gettime`. This one uses a new clock source management framework (gtod - [Generic Time Of Day](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/highres.txt)). A call to `do_realtime`, and it reads from a structure, `struct vsyscall_gtod_data`'s `wall_time_sec` field. This structure is maintained by [`update_vsyscall`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/entry/vsyscall/vsyscall_gtod.c#L29), from the same timekeeper struct as the above.

### tl;dr

The answer is: **yes**, they get the time from the same clock source.

Comment: What do you mean by "if the clock is CLOCK_REALTIME" ?

Comment: @KirilKirov `clock_gettime`'s first argument is a clock ID. One possible value is the mentioned `CLOCK_REALTIME`.

Comment: Yes, I know the first argument, but I did not understand what you meant. Thanks for the clarification and the edit, I get it now.

Comment: To be pedantic _return the epoch_ must be _return duration in seconds **since UNIX epoch**_.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin : There.

Comment: The details about `clock_gettime()` are totally wrong, that is an old implementation. This function resides in [the VDSO](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html).  `__vdso_clock_gettime` does not call `__vdso_gettimeofday`.

Comment: Okie, write your own answer then, please :)

Comment: @Koshinae I prefer commenting on inaccurate answers.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Okay, it was embarrassing for me :)

Comment: @Koshinae Aww, do not take it personally.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Can do sir.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - okay, do you say, that they are semantically different then (ignoring for a moment the implementation)? I guess not, because the behavior should be still the same, but still..

Comment: @KirilKirov `clock_gettime` has nanosecond resolution. `gettimeofday` only has microsecond resolution, so that `clock_gettime` implemented in terms of `gettimeofday` did not have nanosecond resolution.